error after running knife bootstrap command "knife bootstrap 172.31.37.8 --connection-user ec2-user --sudo -i node-key.pem -N node1"
output
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:31: warning: already initialized constant Chef::Knife::Bootstrap::SUPPORTED_CONNECTION_PROTOCOLS
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:31: warning: previous definition of SUPPORTED_CONNECTION_PROTOCOLS was here
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant Chef::Knife::Bootstrap::WINRM_AUTH_PROTOCOL_LIST
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:32: warning: previous definition of WINRM_AUTH_PROTOCOL_LIST was here
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:350: warning: already initialized constant Chef::Knife::Bootstrap::DEPRECATED_FLAGS
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:350: warning: previous definition of DEPRECATED_FLAGS was here
WARNING: You provided --ssh-user. This flag is deprecated. Please use '--connection-user USERNAME' instead.
Creating new client for node1
Creating new node for node1
Connecting to 172.31.37.8
WARN: [SSH] PTY requested: stderr will be merged into stdout
The authenticity of host '172.31.37.8 ()' can't be established.
fingerprint is SHA256:VqFQIH1DufKH4gIlXPbM4geTdXOkW0P2J9KrcttbV9E.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting
? (Y/N) y
WARN: [SSH] PTY requested: stderr will be merged into stdout
WARN: [SSH] connection failed, terminating (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ec2-user@172.31.37.8>)
ERROR: Train::Transports::SSHFailed: SSH session could not be established
i tried knife bootstrap command to attach my node to my chef server but it didnt andd gave me this error instead of desired output.
